# If a person's headache varies in different situations, at different times, "and/or" depending on their mood, it indicates... - differences in meaning?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

**Example 1**

> If a person's headache varies in different situations, at different times, **or** depending on their mood, it indicates the headache is caused by psychological factors.

**Example 2**

> If a person's headache varies in different situations, at different times, **and** depending on their mood, it indicates the headache is caused by psychological factors.

What are the differences in meaning between the two examples?

**Is my interpretation correct?**

In Example 1, the use of "or" suggests that the variation in the person's headache can be attributed to different factors independently. But it does not necessarily require all three conditions to be present simultaneously.

As for Example 2, all three conditions need to be present for the headache to be attributed to psychological factors.

Comment: You're over-thinking this one. I doubt any native speaker would ever intend or understand the ***and / or*** choice as reflecting something to do with how "independent" the three mentioned variables might be. Definitely the idea that ***and*** here might imply ***all three variations must apply*** is completely spurious. But I wouldn't like to say which conjunction is more common - that would probably vary depending on both the exact wording *and* the exact context within which the utterance was made, as well as arbitrary preference by the specific speaker.

Comment: @vincentlin  Ignore the very confusing comment above.   You are correct.  There is a difference in meaning between your examples, and it is just as you say.  "A, B, and C" A applies, B applies, and C applies, and this very sentence is another example!.  On the other hand, "A, B, or C" means any of the three is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

In that context, both sentences mean the same thing, but come to that meaning in slightly different ways.

Logically, it makes no sense for someone's headache to vary only if all three conditions have changed, so that interpretation is out.

The version with "or" means *the headache will vary if the situation, time or mood is different*.

The version with "and" means *the situation, time and mood are all (independent) factors in the variance of the headache*.

Comment: This is wildly incorrect. Asserting in the first example that the headache varies if the situation, time or mood is different' is a logical fallacy called "assuming the converse" You cannot conclude that the headache will vary at all.  You are reversing the arrow of causality; <A> implies <B> does not follow from <B> implies <A>. In the assertion about the second example, there is absolutely no reason why the factors must be independent - for example it could be true that the "situations" only occur at specific "times".  More importantly, all of them must be present to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @BadZen Of course the sentences *literally* have different meanings, but *pragmatically*, there's only one possible reading.